# Writing a data frame to a csv file in Python/Pandas and making sure all rows stay the same

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data frame that I'm trying to write and save to a csv file. When I generate the data frame, the column "phone" - originally displays the phone number. However, when I write the data file to a csv file and test to see if I can retrieve the csv file, the phone numbers now display in scientific notation (ie. 1.2022668e+10).

How can I write the data frame to a csv file, and retrieve it so that the "phone" column preserves the phone numbers, and not display as scientic notation. My code is below:

```
yelp_df = get_ratings() -> the data frame is generated in the def function "get_ratings()"

df = pd.DataFrame(yelp_df, columns = ['name', 'rating', 'review_count', 'phone', 'location'])

df.to_csv(r'yelp_data.csv', index = False, header=True)

pd.read_csv('yelp_data.csv')
```

Comment: Simplest way would be to convert the column to string type before writing it to file, then convert it back when you read it again

Comment: scientific notation should apply to floats but not integers, what are your phone numbers casted as?